# <a> tag doesn't work as a link in mobile mode

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have an a tag in a view that works properly in desktop mode, but when I resize the page to mobile, it  no longer works as a link is just a text

here is my html code:

```
<div class="gbox-container">
        <div class="item a">...</div>
        <div class="devider">...</div>
        <div class="item b">
            <div class="tabs">
                <section id="tab-8">
                    <div class="details-box">
                        <div class="testRow"><a href="account/login"> Link Text </a></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item c">...</div>
    </div>
```

The reason the  link does not work is because of the '.tabs' class

here is tabs class:

```
@media (max-width: 500px)
.tabs {
    width: 90vw;
}
```

The link works properly when I delete the 'width: 90vw;'

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem -> https://jsfiddle.net/agfqbdp3/ . What do you mean by : ' it doesn't work ' ?

Comment: What do you expect a link with `href=#` to do?

Comment: thanks for response,i mean in mobile mode, nothing happens when I click on the link text. While it should go to the address in href.

Comment: In my project, the value of href is not #. I changed the value just to keep the question short

Comment: Maybe it's because your trying to press it on mobile, but your finger is pressing other things as well. Try putting **a:hover** and test it on your desktop to see if the mouse hover will work. Other test that you can do is setting a size for you a tag and see if the click will work with a bigger space

Comment: @GrazielleCarvalho thanks for response but that wasn't the reason

Comment: @MihaiT  jsfiddle.net/agfqbdp3 does not have a mobile mode

Comment: with the code you provided we cannot help you. Please provide an example that reproduces your problem

Comment: We need to see some of your CSS if the suspicion is that the a element is being covered.

Comment: @MihaiT I updated my question, 'width: 90vw;'  is the reason of problem, but I don't know how to solve it :((

Comment: @AHaworth thanks for response, I update my question, would you please check it out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem reported was that the link was not clickable on a smaller device and from info in the comments it sounded as though that was because of setting the tabs div with a fixed width.

However, I have run the code given and it seems to work with a couple of minor alterations. The media query had some missing brackets which may have meant (depending on where it was placed in the style sheet) that some related styling also did not work. I added color just so it was obvious that the styling for smaller devices was being correctly applied. Run the snippet full page and gradually decrease the window width to test. Without having the full CSS and content of a real page it is not possible to say whether this works in the real case or not.

```css
@media (max-width: 500px)
{
.tabs {
    width: 90vw;
    background-color: cyan;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="gbox-container">
        <div class="item a">...</div>
        <div class="devider">...</div>
        <div class="item b">
            <div class="tabs">
                <section id="tab-8">
                    <div class="details-box">
                        <div class="testRow"><a href="account/login"> Link Text </a></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item c">...</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I set background-color to 'tabs' class, It completely covers the <a> tag. and I cant see my link text

Comment: 'display: revert;' in 'tabs' class solved problem

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 500px)
.tabs {
    width: 90vw;
    display: revert;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.